# Velocity.js and memory leaks

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

I'm working on an HTML5 game. The user interface is fairly complex and dynamic: I use a lot of  containers and I populate them with various velocity animated DOM elements. Such containers get created and destroyed all the time so I'm wondering if I should worry about about memory leaks in the velocity framework. Is there something I can or should do to help the garbage collector do its work?
Thank you.

Comment: So you have memory leaks, or you're worried that some day in the distant future under circumstances you can't predict, you *may* have leaks?

Comment: I'm worried about memory leaks I could have in the future, so I'm asking if there are some good practices I should follow in using velocity in my scenario.

Comment: Usually leaks happen by accident. Unless you're retaining tons of objects for no reason, you'll be fine. If you have problems, fix them. This question is simply way too broad and hypothetical to answer. If you *have* a leak, then Stack Overflow could help you fix it.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I was worried about the way I create and destroy DOM nodes containing a lot of animated elements. It's my first project using velocity and I'm new to common pitfalls or bad practices.